# Docker UDP 'response'

Tags: iptables, docker-swarm, ipvs

Simply put, I have 2 containers for a service in a swarm mode. Container  receives udp packets and sends them back to multiple clients, which ip's and ports are stored in db. Load-balancing: packets from one IP go to same container.

So, here is the situation:

- container-1 receives packet from client-1 (`10.255.0.2:5874` - src ip and port of packet we see inside container) and send him response back (successfully).
- container-2 receives packet from client-2 (`10.255.0.2:5875`) and wants to send this packet back to both clients (using addresses from db), *but* only client-2 receives the packet!

Debug information I gathered so far:

```
sudo nsenter --net=/run/docker/netns/ingress_sbox

root@alpom-qa:~# sudo iptables --list -t mangle
sudo: unable to resolve host alpom-qa: Resource temporarily unavailable
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MARK       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:5070 MARK set 0x161
MARK       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:5062 MARK set 0x163
MARK       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:5080 MARK set 0x16b
MARK       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt MARK set 0x18f
MARK       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:sip MARK set 0x192
MARK       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:sip-tls MARK set 0x192

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MARK       all  --  anywhere             10.255.0.7           MARK set 0x161
MARK       all  --  anywhere             10.255.0.9           MARK set 0x163
MARK       all  --  anywhere             10.255.0.5           MARK set 0x16b
MARK       all  --  anywhere             10.255.10.115        MARK set 0x18f
MARK       all  --  anywhere             10.255.0.11          MARK set 0x192
```

Docker uses IPVS for load-balancing:

```
root@alpom-qa:~# ipvsadm
IP Virtual Server version 1.2.1 (size=4096)
Prot LocalAddress:Port Scheduler Flags
  -> RemoteAddress:Port           Forward Weight ActiveConn InActConn
FWM  353 rr
  -> 10.255.10.245:0              Masq    1      0          0
FWM  355 rr
  -> 10.255.10.246:0              Masq    1      0          0
FWM  363 rr
  -> 10.255.11.61:0               Masq    1      0          0
FWM  399 rr
  -> 10.255.11.91:0               Masq    1      0          13
FWM  402 rr
  -> 10.255.11.93:0               Masq    1      0          1
  -> 10.255.11.94:0               Masq    1      0          1
```

and connection(filtered out udp):

```
root@alpom-qa:~# ipvsadm -lc
IPVS connection entries
pro expire state       source             virtual            destination
UDP 04:59  UDP         10.10.0.1:5874     172.18.0.2:sip     10.255.11.93:sip
UDP 04:59  UDP         10.10.0.1:5875     172.18.0.2:sip     10.255.11.94:sip
```

And tcpdump:

```
sudo tcpdump -i any src 10.255.11.93 -nn
```

shows only entries like `13:03:28.280287 IP 10.255.11.93.5060 > 10.255.0.2.5874: SIP`

---

Looks like if we send udp packet to `10.255.0.2.5875` not from `10.255.11.94`(as shown in connection list), it somehow gets lost.